# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 - Firefox crashes on load

Tags: firefox, mate

Ubuntu Mate 16.04 installed on Rpi3, and recently stopped loading.

1) It worked well for few months (I guess that some update messed it up ).

2) Another RPi was installed with Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and again - fails to load Firefox.

3) Both RPis run Chromium (as an alternative ) and connect to the internet ok.

4) Error logs were sent to Mozilla - but no change for two weeks now.

Any Idea why/ how to solve it ?

> Edit 1: After uninstall v55, and during installation of v52, en error occured-

```
guy@guy-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -i firefox-dbg_52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_armhf.deb 
[sudo] password for guy: 
(Reading database ... 205031 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack firefox-dbg_52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-dbg (52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) over (52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of firefox-dbg:
 firefox-dbg depends on firefox (= 52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
  Package firefox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package firefox-dbg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 firefox-dbg
guy@guy-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guy, in searching it looks like this latest Fire fox version is not yet compatible.  The work around is to downgrade to the earlier version.  Copy the  current mozilla directory, purge the current version of Firefox, then re-install, an earlier version.  Might need to go back to version 52 from 55, the current version.

Comment: did you get the same error as i did ?

Answer (score 0):

As said version 55 still not stable [RapberryPi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=190945)

In this link there is a guide to downgrade to version 52.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Helo,
 I fought the same error for quite a few hours. I am using file:
 firefox_52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_armhf.deb

Notice the difference in name? When I finally got the file 
(maybe correct one?) everything worked well.

Be sure to do a sudo apt-mark hold firefox

Followed: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/firefox-55-0-2-doesnt-start-crashes-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberrypi-3/14637/2

Recently I was unable to find this particular file name. My filesize is 48405528 if that helps.

Also.
Ben ARS w4qed